# How to escape the double quotes and open brackets in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image] 
I tried to get the value from the **Bus Stop** Table which is the same id by using

```
{{ \App\Busstop::where('id',$order->bus_stops)->pluck('busstop') }}
```

But this codes is showing me like the json data or curly brackets.I only want to get plain words witout double quotes and curly brackets.

Comment: `pluck()` returns a collection. Use `first()` on it (if it'll only ever be one item) or `implode()` on it (if it'll be more than one sometimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implode` instead of `pluck` like so :

```
{{ \App\Busstop::where('id',$order->bus_stops)->implode('busstop', ', '); }}
```